# How can I set all arrow in vertically in css?

Tags: css

I use font awesomw icon to put right angle arrow but How do i set in equall size verically in css?

Here is my Html Code:-

```
    <div class="list">
         <ul>
             <li>JAVA Developer<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></li>
             <li>Python Developer<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></li>
             <li>UX Designer<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

My example demo:-
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li{    
   position: relative;
}
li i{
   position: absolute;
   right: 65%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multitude of solutions here, I'm going to show a solution based on fixed width an absolute positioning for the icons:

```css
.list ul li {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
  width: 8em;
}

.list ul li i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>JAVA Developer<i class="fas fa-angle-right">></i></li>
    <li>Python Developer<i class="fas fa-angle-right">></i></li>
    <li>UX Designer<i class="fas fa-angle-right">></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If i tried this code then all the list item also coming in vertical..borders arrows nd texts all merged